# Retrieve the access token with GoogleCredentials class in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I am using the library **com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.9.0** in my Google App Engine application. My application makes requests to another application with its default application engine service account with domain delegation enabled. I have many users that I need to cache their tokens for one hour. The problem is that I do not know how to recover the access token before making the request.

```
credential = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault()
    .createScoped(scopes)
    .createDelegated(user).toBuilder().build();
```

At this moment access token is null.

```
credential.getAccessToken()
```

And if I update the token to retrieve a new access token, an error occurs:

```
credential.refreshAccessToken();
```

**The OAuth2Credentials instance does not support updating the access token. You must use an instance with a new access token or a derived type that is compatible with the update.**

The request is made with the google-api-client library.

```
import com.google.api.client.http.*;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchTransport; 
import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;

HttpRequestFactory factory = new UrlFetchTransport().createRequestFactory(new 
HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential));
```

Thanks.